# Confusing syntax with anonymous template types?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template <class T, class U> decltype(*(T*)(0) * *(U*)(0)) mul(T x, U y) {
   return x * y;
}
```

This piece of code was taken from Stroustrup's [C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#suffix-return). I understand what it does, which is multiply two objects of varying types. What perplexes me is the syntax between the template parameters and the function definition. What is happening inside `decltype`? I take it that it's dereferencing an unnammed `T` pointer initialized to 0, and multiplying it by an unnamed `U` pointer being dereferenced and initialized in the same way. Am I right?

Well, if this is what is happening, then isn't the use of pointers, dereferences, and extra parenthesis superfluous? Couldn't I initialize the types like this while maintaining the desired effect?:

```
template <class T, class U> decltype(T(0) * U(0)) mul(T x, U y) {
   return x * y;
}
```

This looks much cleaner to me, and it *does* have the same effect when multiplying two numbers like in the first...

```
mul(4, 3); // 12
```

So why does Stroustrup insist on using complex pointer, dereference and initialization syntax? This is, of course, before he introduced the new `auto` syntax. But anyway, **my question is**: Is there any difference between the two above forms of type initialization? Where he uses pointers and instantly dereferences them instead of simply doing what I did, which was to initialize the types with no pointers or dereferencing? Any response is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when given a `T` that isn't constructable from an `int`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your version is *not* equivalent.

1. Your version supposes that both `T` and `U` can be constructed from `0`. It's obviously wrong to expect this from matrices, yet they can be multiplied.
2. `T(0)` yields a temporary (that may bind to `T&&`) whilst `*(T*(0))` yields a reference to an existing object (that is, `T&`), therefore a different operator might be selected.

However, neither Stroustrup's version nor yours end up being used *in practice*. At an equivalent level of compiler implementation, one would use:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
decltype(std::declval<T>() * std::declval<U>()) mul(T x, U y);
```

But it's failing to take advantage of **Late Return Type** specification, built to allow postponing the declaration of the return type *after* the function's arguments declaration: `auto f(int, int) -> int`. Once the arguments have been declared, they can be *used*, which is incredibly useful for `decltype`!

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto mul(T x, U y) -> decltype(x * y);
```

This latter form is guaranteed to pick the same operator overload than the function body, at the cost of repetition (unfortunately).

Comment: Why don't we have to put 0 in the parameters of `std::declval<T>()`?

Comment: @David: there is no argument to `declval`, so I don't quite understand your question, sorry :x

Comment: You're doing `std::declval<T>() * std::declval<U>()` but how do we know these are numbers? Where I do `T(0)` I'm initializing it to 0; why don't we to that in the parameters of `declval`?

Comment: @David: `std::declval<T>()` has a return type `T&`, therefore the expression `std::declval<T>() * std::declval<U>()` is seen by the compiler as a call of the form `operator*(T&,U&)` and it looks for a declaration of `operator*` which will match this form (maybe after some conversions). The value `0` is useless, because in an **unevaluated context** (the technical name for expressions within `decltype` or `sizeof` in C++) only the type matters, and as C++ is a statically typed language, values do not influence types.

Answer (score 5):

Your version of the code supposes that T and U have default constructors. Stroustrup version doesn't, it creates a dummy object by dereferencing a null pointer. That doesn't matter of course because that code is not meant to be executed, it's only meant to be parsed to know the resulting type.

Answer (score 4):

`decltype` content is unevaluated context; it doesn't matter what is there, as long as it results with a type. Think for a second about `T` being defined like this:

```
struct T
{
    int operator*(const U &) { return 2; }
};
```

It doesn't have constructor taking `int` or any type that `int` is convertible to; therefore, `T(0)` does not result in an object, even in unevaluated context of `decltype`. Therefore, using unevaluated null references is possibly the easiest way to get proper type.

Bottom line: you don't know what constructors do `T` and `U` have, so you should use null reference that references dummy object of proper type.